# Dynamic Facebook share button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook

I'm currently trying to make my facebook share button dynamic. What I'm currently doing is replacing the data-href in the div(I'm using html 5 code)

Apparently I have a list of urls loaded in my javascript. Whenever I click on a button, it replaces the link in my data-href, but when I click the share button, it still uses the preloaded link that was first loaded onto it. How do I change the share button link without having to reload the page all over again?

I replace the data-href using this code:

```
        $(".fb-like").attr('data-href',youtube_str+link);
```

Answer (score 2):

Bad news, that's not possible using html5 code, good news you can solve that using XFBML.

Just change your `<html>` tag to `<html xmlns:fb="http://ogp.me/ns/fb#">` so it works on older IE versions

And change your share buttons to this:

```
<fb:share-button href="http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/" type="button_count"></fb:share-button>
```

**Note:** You may have to change the type for the one you want.

Then everytime you change the url and I'm assuming you're using the Javascript SDK, just do this:

```
FB.XFBML.parse();
```

It will parse every XFBML on your page, if you don't want to parse every tag, you can use a DOM selector:

```
FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('foo'));
```

More info here [Facebook Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) and here [Facebook Dev wiki](http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/FB.XFBML.parse)